# How to unhide master of UISplitViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I have created a `UISplitViewController` in **appDelegate** class. And I am hiding master view in one of my **viewController** on button touch like this:

```
splitVC.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
[splitVC presentModalViewController:[[splitVC viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1] animated:NO];
```

Again if the same button is touched, I want the master view to unhide. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `[splitVC dismissModalViewController:YES];`?

Let me know if that is something that helped you.